# Is it possible to avoid awarding a bounty on a low quality post?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I got only one answer to my question and it doesn't answer the question. After IMMENSE research I found my own answer and posted it.

**BUT**

The question has a bounty. This bounty is automatically going to be forever rewarded to a low-effort post.

I can't award my own answer, so is there a way to avoid awarding low effort?

Note: I accept the cost of the bounty. This is a question about where the benefit goes - the "award." I found it in the community wiki section about **Automatic Awarding**.

Comment: Did you put the bounty on the question or did someone else?

Comment: Was the answer posted *before* the bounty? If it was posted before, it does not win 50% of the bounty. If it was posted *after* and it did not get any upvotes, it will not be awarded 50% of the bounty. If the answer received at least 2 upvotes after the bounty had been offered, the system awards 50% of the bounty, if the benefactor does not award it to anyone.

Comment: @RobertColumbia - That is an encyclopedia.

Comment: Then the LQ answer gets nothing. The system automatically  awards half the bounty amount ONLY if the benefactor (or the OP) does not award it to anyone. The benefactor cannot award the bounty to themself. Why are users downvoting this post?

Comment: But it contains the answer to your question.

Comment: Almost. I could not determine if those listed conditions were AND or OR conditions for the award. The wording is ambiguous. The LQ has a score > 2 (first condition met) but posted before the bounty (second condition not met).

Comment: If the other answer was there before you started the bounty, it won't get anything unless you personally award it (or accept it, I'm not sure if accepting causes auto-awarding the bounty only for answers posted during the bounty period or also for earlier answers). Doesn't seem likely that you do that. Unless somebody posts an answer that gets enough upvotes before the bounty period is over, your bounty just fizzles.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible to stop a bounty.  If it were, it would be abused by people who want the attention, but not the cost.  The only way to remove a bounty is to have a moderator refund it, but that generally only happens when it looks like the bounty was posted in bad faith.

Beyond that...you're paying for attention.  You're not guaranteed an answer, just that the question gets that extra attention.

Comment: I get that, but the question is about preventing the automatic award to a low quality post. This has nothing to do with cost-free attention. My cost is the same, the question only deals with the automated direction of the benefit. It is answered in the comments

Comment: Your basic question was if you could stop a bounty.  I answered that.  The rest of the details are answered in the comments and the duplicate.

Comment: OK, well, I already knew the answer to my 150 character summary, but thank you.

Comment: Fixed the title to match the question