# Let's close the [awards] ceremony

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The tag [awards](/questions/tagged/awards) has 11 questions, no tag wiki, and is used for three different purposes:

- Awarding [bounties](/questions/tagged/bounties), e.g. [Is it possible to avoid awarding a bounty on a low quality post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335579/is-it-possible-to-avoid-awarding-a-bounty-on-a-low-quality-post)
- Awarding [badges](/questions/tagged/badges), e.g. [Auto bounty award bug?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128106/auto-bounty-award-bug)
- Prizes, e.g. [Awards, Prizes and Certifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122272/awards-prizes-and-certifications)

Should we burninate it? If yes, what blue tag would apply [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215376/295232) (since it has such a low score, I tend to not giving it any).

Comment: I've retagged the question you mentioned.

Comment: I see downvotes without comments. If any of the downvotes would elaborate in an answer, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've removed the tag on the six remaining questions (and did some other cleanup while I was at it). The tag will be deleted by the system in 24 hours.

Answer (score 12):

I agree with getting rid of it.

Questions about bounties should simply be tagged [bounties](/questions/tagged/bounties). We don't need an extra tag for awarding them. Same goes for [badges](/questions/tagged/badges).

The 3rd question you mention is off-topic. Should SE reward us with something, we have [swag](/questions/tagged/swag).

Let [awards](/questions/tagged/awards) go. We can fix this by editing the remaining questions, it's not a great number of questions after all.

Answer (score 3):

I also agree that it's not worth to keep the [awards](/questions/tagged/awards) tag.

I just want to add that 6 out of these 11<sup>1</sup> questions are closed [on hold] or as [duplicate], one more is marked with [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). The circumstance that there's no *usage guidance* just enforces it is useless here.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>ATM of writing there are only 10 questions carrying that tag, maybe a deleted one I can't see.</sub>

Comment: now only 9, some have been edited in the meanwhile.

Comment: I just deleted [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129434/278659), which is closed and anyway seems to be dupey of a better-received question.

Comment: Also tried to VTD [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37937/278659), but it can't be VTDed because it's a dupe target for [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38411/278659), which can't be VTDed because it's a dupe target for [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38634/278659). Start at the bottom ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor maybe you can VTD it now?

Comment: @Glorfindel And done. Teamwork and patience FTW.